# Update File Path in Most Recent Used Explorer List Which is Store in Binary

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, mru

I'm having trouble understanding how to edit a file path of Binary Entry, what I'm trying to accomplish is to change the file path of the most recently used list after migrating from Folder Redirection to OneDrive Redirect to correct the shortcuts for my end users.  Using Powershell I believe I need to edit Binary Values in this location

> Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RecentDocs

But I am struggling to understand how to update the file path when it's written in binary, does Powershell have a way to convert this to a human readable string and then can I updated it and convert it back?

Comment: Undocumented Microsoft binary data. But the path is not stored there (only the filename?) so I don't really understand the question.